# Como verificar se ao menos um checkbox está ativado

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

Tenho um conjunto de checkboxes e preciso de uma função em javascript que, ao submeter o formulário, verifique se ao menos uma está marcada e exiba o alerta para selecionar se não estiver. Não posso usar radio neste caso, têm que ser checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="opção1" value="true" />
<input type="checkbox" name="opção2" value="true" />
<input type="checkbox" name="opção3" value="true" />
<input type="checkbox" name="opção4" value="true" />
<input type="submit" value="ENVIAR" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem algumas formas de fazer isso. No código abaixo eu coloquei uma class check em todos os checkboxes para ficar mais simples de pegar todos os elementos com javascript, ele testa um por um para ver se está apertado e se não estiver apertado, ele aperta o primeiro.

**HTML**

```
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="opção1" value="true"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="opção1" value="true"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="opção1" value="true"/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" name="opção1" value="true"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
    checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("check")
    noCheckedBoxes = true
    for (i = 0; i< checkBoxes.length; ++i) {
        if(checkBoxes[i].checked) {
            noCheckedBoxes = false
        }
    }
    if(noCheckedBoxes) {
        checkBoxes[0].checked = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

uma outra forma mais "enxuta" seria utilizando de *forEach* em um *querySelectorAll* para verificar todos os inputs do tipo checkbox:

```
let noCheckedBox = false;
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").forEach(e=> {
    if (!e.checked) noCheckedBox = true;
});
if (noCheckedBox) alert("Nenhum checkbox selecionado!");
```